# Hermes setup [react-native": 0.61.5] / libhermes-executor-debug

Tags: react-native, hermes-jms, react-native-hermes

I updated few weeks ago to react-native : 0.61.5 and tried to set up hermes engine, and tried it on android. 
After followed the steps here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes
Build in both, release and debug, mode are successful.

However, the app, then, crash instantly. 
Through Android Studio, I'm getting this error : `E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-debug.so caused by: dlopen`

I tried to add :

```
maven { url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")}
```

Tried : `./gradlew clean` of course, `rm -rf node_modules && yarn install` , none of this fixed my problem :/

Can anyone could help please ?

Comment: Those instructions assume you are using an app based on a the standard RN template. Are you? See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0b6fad6e7ac32d6eac9dd3760c24a5f985cfade2/template/android/app/build.gradle#L203) for the part of the `build.gradle` template that would include `libhermes-executor-debug.so` in the apk.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Yeah, I suppose I am. And concerning the build.gradle file reference you say, I have the same configuration.

Comment: Which `.so` files do you have in your APK?